# OrientDB not allowing update queries after running for some time

Tags: orientdb

We are running a orientdb server close to 40GB. Whilst running server components on the orientdb server for some time, the server is not allowing for any update although it is possible to use read only queries.

We are using both the rest API, the Java API and use connection pools to get connections.

We would like to know if anyone else faced the same issue, what was the solution and the exact cause.

OrientDB version: 2.1.12
Java: Java 8.0.31
OS: CentOS Linux 7 64 bit
RAM: 16GB
MAX HEAP: 9216Xmx
Diskcache: 4096m

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by phrase server does not allow any update ?

Comment: Have you already tried to restart the server?

Comment: Hi Andrey, From the RestAPI, JAVA API and even from the studio, it is possible to execute select queries but it doesn' t execute any insert or update queries.

Comment: Yes Alessandro, After restarting db seems to work fine. But after some time again it behaves the same.

Comment: Do you encounter exception or something like that ? How do you understand that updates are prohibited ?

Comment: Hi Andrey, When this happens even if we run a update query from studio it keeps on executing from the studio forever. And non of my components can execute write operations. But there were no exceptions in the orient db log.

Comment: In such case, you should open issue in GitHub and send full thread dump. We will help you to resolve given issue.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I have raised a issue in github with the log https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6328